# Insert new element as the head of the Linkedlist Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

I want to add an element at the beginning of a Linkedlist, but `None` is added instead of the actual element

```
class Node:
    #initialize the head node to none if not provided and set the next node to none
    def __init__(self,data=None):
        self.data = data
        self.next = None

class Linkedlist:
    def __init__(self):
        self.head = Node()


    def append(self,data):
        #creating the node with the data parameter
        new_node = Node(data)
        current_node = self.head
        while current_node.next is not None:
            current_node = current_node.next
        #when we have reached the end of list
        current_node.next = new_node


    def display(self):
        #container for the nodes
        node_elements = []
        current_node = self.head

        while current_node.next is not None:
            current_node = current_node.next
            node_elements.append(current_node.data)
        print(node_elements)

    #Here is where there is the issue
    def insert_as_first_element(self,data):
        new_node = Node(data)
        new_node.next = self.head
        self.head = new_node
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `insert` method seems fine. The problems seems to be that you initialize `self.head` as an empty `Node()` but never update that node's `data`. Adding a `repr` method to `Node` as

```
def __repr__(self):
    return "(%r, %r)" % (self.data, self.next)
```

we see that after appending or inserting the numbers from `range(10)`, the result looks like this:

```
(None, (0, (1, (2, (3, (4, (5, (6, (7, (8, (9, None)))))))))))
(9, (8, (7, (6, (5, (4, (3, (2, (1, (0, (None, None)))))))))))
```

Instead, you should initialize `self.head` as `None` and add an accordant check to `append`:

```
def __init__(self):
    self.head = None

def append(self,data):
    if self.head is None:
        self.head = Node(data)
    else:
        cur = self.head
        while cur.next is not None:
            cur = cur.next
        cur.next = Node(data)
```

Then, the result looks like this:

```
(0, (1, (2, (3, (4, (5, (6, (7, (8, (9, None))))))))))
(9, (8, (7, (6, (5, (4, (3, (2, (1, (0, None))))))))))
```

You also have to adapt your `display` method as it skips the first element in the list, which is probably why you did not notice the bug for `append`.

```
def display(self):
    node_elements = []
    cur = self.head
    while cur is not None:
        node_elements.append(cur.data)
        cur = cur.next
    print(node_elements)
```

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is not with the inserting *per se*, it starts much earlier with the empty (`None`) node at the base of your `LinkedList`. Then when you *insert* an element at the beginning of the list, that node gets pushed down the structure which makes it appear in your `display()` call (given that `current_node.next` is now this *empty* node).

An easy fix, if you want to keep an empty node at the root of your linked list, is to just leave it there and operate with its children:

```
def insert_as_first_element(self, data):
    new_node = Node(data)
    new_node.next = self.head.next
    self.head.next = new_node
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in your `display` function, where you need to switch the order of extracting data and moving on to the next node. Otherwise you won't hit the first node that you've entered in your list.

> ```
>     while current_node.next is not None:
>        node_elements.append(current_node.data)
>        current_node = current_node.next
> ```

Comment: As others have noted, this leaves an invisible empty node at the top of the list.